# Compare distributions of values in two arrays (of same size) using range argument

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, histogram, data-visualization

I want to compare distributions of values in two arrays (of same size), but the histogram display changes when I specify range argument:

```
def plot_compare(values1, values2, bins=100, range=None):
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111) 
    ax.hist(values1.ravel(), alpha=0.5, bins=bins, range=range, color= 'b', label='1')
    ax.hist(values2.ravel(), alpha=0.5, bins=bins, range=range, color= 'r', label='2')
    ax.legend(loc='upper right', prop={'size':14})
    plt.show()


plot_compare(a1, a2)
```

[image]

```
plot_compare(a1, a2, range=(-1200, 300))
```

[image]

How do I make the proper comparison? My goal is to get a visual clue of how the values are different in two arrays.

Both arrays have the same number of values.

Should I use same number of bins for the two arrays (but bins would be of different width), or should I use different number of bins (but bins of the same width)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use bins of the same width, if you want to compare two histograms. Therefore your second plot is correct.

The difference between two plots is that when range is specified, the width of bins is computed based on this range (i.e. your range is divided by the number of bins). 
With the first plot, the ranges of both arrays are different. Therefore the bins width is different.